# jhipster - war deployed on jboss server

Tags: jboss, http-status-code-404, jhipster

I'm trying to deploy my jhipster .war on a jboss 6.4. I can access to the main page but cannot log in. I have the message "Failed to sign in! Please check your credentials and try again". On the Chrome console i have this error : http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/authenticate?cacheBuster=1492172408521 404 (Not Found)
But this works fine with the mvnw command on the embedded server(tomcat).

What is the problem with jboss ?

edit:

jhipster version : 3.12.2.
Monolithic application.
Jwt authentication. 
Mysql database.

Ok now i started a new fresh project, i deployed it on jboss 6.4 and I still have the problem, i cannot authenticate. I have this on the console when i go the main page : GET localhost:8080/myapp/api/profile-info?cacheBuster=1492674235‌​919 404 (Not Found) and GET localhost:8080/myapp/api/account?cacheBuster=1492674235931 404 (Not Found).

Comment: Please add the jhipster version you are using, the kind of architecture you chose and how you generated your war, and other details. Answers might come faster if you do.

Comment: @matthieusb I'm using jhipster 3.12.2. It's is a monolithic application with a jwt authentication using mysql database. I'm upgrading to the latest version now..

Comment: Is everything working when you launch it locally ? Can you show the logs you obtain when you launch your app from jboss ? (Don't hesitate to edit your question by the way)

Comment: @matthieusb When i launch it from jboss 6.4.7 i got some errors (see my edits).

Comment: Well I never encountered that kind of error. Is your database running ? Is it correctly initialized ? Though I think this would work even without a started database. How did you produce the production jar ? Maybe take a look at the official to documentation to deploy to production : https://jhipster.github.io/production/ It looks like some dependecies are missing or were not compiled correctly ...

Comment: My database is running and correctly initialized. Ok now i started a new fresh project, i deployed it on jboss 6.4 and I still have the problem, i cannot authenticate. I have this on the console when i go the main page : GET http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/profile-info?cacheBuster=1492674235919 404 (Not Found) and GET http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/account?cacheBuster=1492674235931 404 (Not Found).  Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Well I am not sure I can help you there, I've never seen this before. Have you considered upgrading your jhipster version ? Is it still working as a local project without deploying to jboss ? The 404 error indicates that the back end is not responding as if it were not up and running. Have you tried calling your backend manually through *curl* for example ?

Comment: i upgraded jhipster to the latest version and it is still working on a local project without deploying to jboss. Now the jboss server is correctly launched and of course the back end is not responding when i try to authenticate. Sorry i don't know how to do that, i have never heard "curl"..

Comment: Curl is just a way to launch http requests through the command line (Available on linux). I am afraid I can't be of any more help, I am not able to reproduce your problem for now. maybe you could file a bug on github ? (Not sure this is a bug though, they may tell you that this has no place on Github). See the issue section there : https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster Be careful to follow the instructions when reporting your problem.

Comment: ok, thank you so much for your help ! :)

Comment: and one last thing. Why the production profile is always launched by default ? In tomcat 8 it launches with the dev profile but not with jboss.. How can I force the jboss server to launch the dev profile ? thanks

Comment: Depends on how you produce your .war/.jar. The springboot embedded tomcat server will launch with dev profile when you do *./mvnw*. You should produce your .war and specify the dev profile (Maybe look at the documentation I already referenced in one of my comments). Or simply copy your dev configuration in your prod configuration, but I would not advise that as a permanent solution.

Comment: I'm using eclipse as IDE. I choose to make the build with the dev profile : clean package with dev profile but it always launch the production profile. I cannot see the red banner on top left. Ok i'll try something. thanks.

Comment: I come back here.. I have forgotten to say that i'm building my project from a parent project. i put the spring-boot-starter-parent dependency on the parent-project. So may be the problem comes from there ? Something is missing ? ..

Comment: I have never tried that with a jhipster project. Maybe some dependencies are missing and the way you're making the war is incorrect. Good luck

Comment: Ok I succedded to deploy the war on jboss 6.4.7 and authenticate. But when I package the same war on an EAR and deploy to the server, i can access to the main page but still cannot authenticate and can't access to any api urls (404 not found again).